# Api for stories on instagram

Tags: instagram-api, instagram-graph-api, instagram-story

I want to send a request to the API of Instagram for stories that in the API it include the username of the user I want and as response I want the Information of the story and I don't know what API should I exactly use

I have used 'https://www.instagram.com/{username}/?__a=1' as the API but I always get the connection error

Answer (score 0):

I studied the API for Facebook and Instagram a long time ago but the basic concept i think are not changed. You must complete the getting started section from the API Graph of Meta For developers (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/getting-started).

You must create at least on developer account and obtaining the access token for using the REST API.

It is not a simple GET request for using the Graph API. No free launch